Why airflow cannot connect to postgresql?
I have airflow 2.9.0 and PostgreSQL 13.14
I could query from postgres using psycopg2 and PostgresOperator using python code,
but when I use the same as Airflow DAG I get this error:

(connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?


checked host, port, ... all good
the server is running and accepting connections (check by pg_isready)
edited PostgreSQL config (listen_addresses = '*')
edited pg_hba.conf (host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust, host all all ::0/0 trust)

Note that the Airflow webserver fails to start when sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2 ... in the PostgreSQL config file.
Does anyone have an idea what should be done?!
Thanks!
I tried all the suggested solutions over the net, and expected some different procedures!
